# Supermartingale, equivalene of defintions

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Let $X_t \in L^{1}(\mathbb{P})$ be an adapted process $\forall t$. Show that the following definitions are equivalent :

(1) $X$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-supermartingale, i.e. $X_s \geq \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}[X_t|F_s]$ for $0 \leq s \leq t \ \leq T$.

(2) $X_{t-1} \geq \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}[X_t | F_{t-1}]$  $1 \leq t \leq T$

My problem is I do not know where to start and how to show this in a precise way (don't they follow immediately from each other?) and how can I make use of the fact that $X_t \in L^{1}(\mathbb{P})$?

Comment: what's the range of $t$?

Comment: @Ilya: it’s $1 \leq t \leq T$ I forgot to write it at first, edited it now, thank you.

Comment: (2) follows from (1) easily by taking $s=t-1$